# What happens to the previous RDD when it gets transformed into a new RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am a beginner in Apache Spark. What I have understood so far regarding RDDs is that, once a RDD is generated, it cannot be modified but can be transformed into another RDD. Now I have several doubts here:

1. If an RDD is transformed to another RDD on applying some transformation on the RDD, then what happens to the previous RDD? Are both the RDDs stored in the memory?
2. If an RDD is cached, and some transformation is applied on the cached RDD to generate a new RDD, then can there be a scenario that, there is not enough space in RAM to hold the newly generated RDD? In case, such a scenario occurs, how will Spark handle that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Due to Spark's lazy evaluation, nothing happens when you do transformations on RDDs. Spark only starts computing when you call an action (save, take, collect, ...). So to answer your questions,

1. The original RDD stays where it is, and the transformed RDD does not exist / has not been computed yet due to lazy evaluation. Only a query plan is generated for it.
2. Regardless of whether the original RDD is cached, the transformed RDD will not be computed until an action is called. Therefore running out of memory shouldn't happen.

Normally when you run out of memory, either you encounter an OOM error, or the cached RDDs in memory will be spilled onto the disk to free up memory.

Comment: Actually I wanted to know the workflow when an action is invoked. In that case, RDDs will be created right? So when an RDD is transformed into another RDD, what will happen to the previous RDD?

Comment: @SouravHazra if the previous one was not cached, it will not be stored; if cached, it will be stored.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand the answers of the questions you have, you need to know couple of things about spark.

1. Spark evaluation Model (Lazy Evaluation)
2. Spark Operations (Transformations and Actions)
3. Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG)

**Answer to your first Question:**

You could think of RDD as virtual data structure that does not get filled with values unless there is some action called on it which materializes the rdd/dataframe. When you perform transformations it just creates query plan which shows the lazily evaluation behavior of spark. When action gets called, it perform all the transformation based on the physical plan that gets generated. So, nothing happens to the RDDs. RDD data gets pulled into memory when action gets called.

**Answer to your Second Question:**

If an RDD is cached and you perform multiple transformations on top of the cache RDD, actually nothing happens to the RDDs as cache is a transformation operation. Also the RDD that you have cached would be in memory when any action would be performed. So, you won't run out of memory.

You could run into memory issues if you are trying to cache each step of the transformation, which should be avoided.(Whether to cache or not Cache a dataframe/RDD is a million dollar question as beginner but you get to understand that as you learn the basics and spark architecture)

Other workflow where you can run out of memory is when you have huge data size and you are caching the rdd after some transformation as you would like to perform multiple actions on it or it is getting used in the workflow multiple times. In this case you need to verify your cluster configuration and need to make sure that it can handle the data that you are intending to cache.

Comment: Let me place a scenario..I have coded 10 transformations(group by, filter, etc.). Now after the 10th transformation, I have invoked an action (let's say count). Now due to lazy evaluation, Spark will start executing the steps in the DAG it had created, once it encounters the count action. Now, in the first transformation(e.g sc.textfile(filename))first RDD will be created and after second transformation a new RDD will be created(since RDDs can't be modified). Now when the first RDD is transformed to the second RDD during execution of the plan, what will happen to both the RDDs?

Comment: they would be in the memory for that amount of time till the action gets performed. Once you get the result of the action the memory would get released. memory does not get released instantly but it uses LRU (Least recently used algorithm) to remove the RDD that are in memory. Also multiple physical plans get generated out of which one is selected that is cost efficient. Also if you are performing narrow transformation it gets combined and no separate stage gets created for that.